# Pause one scene completely while keeping other scene active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to achieve to pause a scene completely when I am loading an additive scene in the foreground. I know I can pause a game with the following code:

```
void PauseGame ()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

void ResumeGame ()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
```

But how do I pause one scene while keeping the other scene active and running?

Comment: Quite tricky for physics based stuff ... depends totally on your specific app though ... It might e.g. be better to keep references to all Rigidbodies and just set them all `isKinematic`

Comment: Yeah, there are actually quite number of buttons and colliders. I can set buttons to disabled but the colliders and the scripts need to be disabled during the moment. What does setActiveScene() imply?

Comment: It sets a scene as the active scene so when you call `SceneManagement.GetActiveScene` you get that one ;) And when you call `Instantiate` etc the objects are added to the active scene .... doesn't mean much more ;) `The active Scene is the Scene which will be used as the target for new GameObjects instantiated by scripts and from what Scene the lighting settings are used. When you add a Scene additively (see LoadSceneMode.Additive), the first Scene is still kept as the active Scene. Use this to switch the active Scene to the Scene you want as the target.`